# css grid - fill 100% of parent which way - table-cell/float/inline-block?

Tags: html, css

Here is my simple grid

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="top">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which way is the best for fulfill this

- `.left` has 70% of `.wrap` width and 100% of `.wrap` height
- `.right` has 30% of `.wrap` width and 100% of .wrap height
- `.top` and `.bottom` fills 50% height of `.right` and 100% width

It should look like this

[image: grid]

I don't know which way is the best if `table-cell`, `inline-block` or `float`ing. I know that flexbox is the simplest solution, but I'd like to know other ways how to do that.

I created [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grEwJj) as well

Comment: Is helpful my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should be add `box-sizing:border-box` AND `display:inline-block`
To Div's , in css2 We adding `float` Property to Div's.
syntax Error founded at Line 27 `backgroung`

```css
.wrap {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:inline-block;
}
.right {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:inline-block;
}
.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
}
.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="top">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/webafrooz/pen/ZWPBWW

Comment: But where is the .bottom div? I can see only .right - the div with red background:

Comment: Code Has been Edited , Refresh Please!